# OnPostExecute run before doInBackground finish -AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my Android project, I'm using `AsyncTask` for `Facebook API` news feed request.
I'm getting error: `OnPostExecute method executed before doInBackground request finish.`

```
 private class NewsFeedAsyncTask extends AsyncTask < Integer, Integer, Boolean > {

     @Override
     protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer...params) {
        if (Session.getActiveSession().getState().isOpened()) {
            Get_news_feed();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Boolean t) {
         super.onPostExecute(t);
         adapter = new FacebookAdapter(data, context);
         listView.setAdapter(adapter);
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         mPullRefreshListView.onRefreshComplete();
     }
 }
```

**fetchNewsFeed ()**

```
public void fetchNewsFeed() {
    Session.openActiveSessionFromCache(context);
    if (Session.getActiveSession().getState().isOpened()) {
        Request.executeGraphPathRequestAsync(
            Session.getActiveSession(), "me/home", new Request.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(
                    Response response) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**OnActivityCreated()**

```
 @Override
 public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
     new NewsFeedAsyncTask().execute();
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `onPostExecute` method is **always** executed after `doInBackground`.

Your problem is that the `Get_news_feed` method (which is executed in background from the `doInBackground` method) posts some stuff to be done back on the UI thread with `runOnUiThread` and then returns (before the stuff posted on UI thread is executed).

If you expect the `Get_news_feed` to be synchronous (everything done before returning), you should not post anything on the UI thread.

Just do all the UI stuff in `onPostExecute` instead.